# Can i convert left/right animation css3 in translate3D

Tags: css, css-animations

I use this code to fully scroll a div from left to right rotate :

```
0% {left:-270px;}
100% {right:-270px;}
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/xyHwy/

can i transform it into translate3D ?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xyHwy/